# Can i make the LightDM greeter wider?

Tags: ubuntu, lightdm

I am using LightDM on my work laptop (under Ubuntu 18, to log in to Cinnamon). We use LDAP (well, Active Directory) for authentication; when i am in the office, my password is checked against the server, and the result is somehow cached, so that when i am not in the office, i can still log in.

When i log in using these cached credentials, the greeter presents a message telling me that this has happened, and how long i have until the credentials expire.

However, the greeter is not actually big enough to display this message:

[image: photo of the LightDM greeter, with a message overflowing it]

And so i have no idea how long i have left.

Is there a way to make the greeter box considerably wider?

EDIT here is my LightDM greeter configuration:

```
$ lightdm --show-config 2>&1 | grep greeter
C  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
F  greeter-session=unity-greeter
C  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
F  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Comment: Is it LightDM GTK greeter? Looks like it to me anyway. If it's the one, and I'm looking correctly, there isn't such an option. So another possibility could be to install a different greeter that allows for changing the width etc.

Comment: I don't know which greeter it is. Do you know how i can tell? I am afraid that the whole world of Linux windowing is a mystery to me.

Comment: Run this command `lightdm --show-config`, there should be line about the greeter.

Comment: @puzzle It looks like i am running something called unity-greeter - see my edit.